# Easier solution for searching across columns in data.frame

Tags: r, algorithm, search, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a database like the following

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 X Y Z
VIX  SPX  VOL  2 3 4
SPX  VIX  NA   4 4 NA
SPX  NA   NA   2 NA NA
```

I want to isolate the first row with inputs from user as VIX, SPX and VOL. However, in a database like this I do not know in which combination these variables are kept in.

That is we might have VIX as Var1, SPX as Var2 and VOL as Var3 or we might have VOL as Var1, SPX as Var2 and VIX as Var3. In such a case 6 combinations are possible.

I can concatenate strings to create all 6 possibilities in R and do a row look up. But I am looking for an easier algorithm.

I am trying to use subset in to filter one column after another but that is equally cumbersome. Is there an easier way out in R

Comment: So `Var1` or `Var2` or `Var3` should have `VIX` or `SPX` or `VOL` ?? and the output would be the row satisfying this condition?

Comment: Yes, Var1, Var2 and Var3 are column headers and they may have VIX, SPX, VOL in any of the six possible combinations. So if my input from user is VOL, SPX, VIX it should be able to search through the above database and give me the first row as output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `apply` row-wise for the first three columns and check with `grepl` if it has any of the three possible values and finally using `all` we verify that all the three columns for that row has the accepted values.

```
df[apply(df[1:3], 1, function(x) all(grepl("VIX|SPX|VOL", x))), ]

#   Var1 Var2 Var3 X Y Z
#1  VIX  SPX  VOL  2 3 4
```

---

Or as @Cath mentioned in the comments using the above can result into selecting some unnecessary rows. We can change it to

```
df[apply(df[1:3], 1, function(x) all(c("VIX", "SPX", "VOL") %in% x)), ]
```

to ensure that all three unique values are present in the three columns.

Comment: I'd go with `all(c("VIX", "SPX", "VOL") %in% x)` instead of `all(grepl("VIX|SPX|VOL", x))` to avoid selecting rows with for example `VIX VIX VOL` if this can happen

Comment: @Cath Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, all(c("VIX", "SPX", "VOL") %in% c(Var1, Var2, Var3)), by=1:3]$V1]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 X Y Z
#1:  VIX  SPX  VOL 2 3 4
```

The condition `all(c("VIX", "SPX", "VOL") %in% c(Var1, Var2, Var3)` permits to ensure that all 3 values are present among the 3 variables (avoiding to select a row with, for example, `VIX VIX VOL`, in case that may happen).

Answer (score 0):

We can use vectorized `rowSums`

```
df1[rowSums(Reduce(`|`, lapply(c("VIX", "SPX", "VOL"), `==`, df1[1:3])), na.rm = TRUE)==3,]
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 X Y Z
#1  VIX  SPX  VOL 2 3 4
```

---

Or another vectorized method instead of looping through rows.

```
df1[!rowSums(Vectorize(function(x) !x%in% c("VIX", "SPX", "VOL"))(df1[1:3])),]
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 X Y Z
#1  VIX  SPX  VOL 2 3 4
```